# Programatically changing ASP Gridview column header text breaks sorting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have gridview bound to an Entity Data source which works no problem, however when I try to programatically change  a header columns text, it appears to break the styling and will not allow sorting either, below is how I am trapping and changing the Header row column text.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
Protected Sub gv1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gv1.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
            'retrieve the values from the userdeftable



            e.Row.Cells(6).Text = App.Session.Company.UserDef3


        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [HeaderText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.headertext.aspx)-property of the column.

```
Me.gv1.Columns(6).HeaderText = App.Session.Company.UserDef3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Sorted event...

Example of how to toggle `HeaderText` to show the order of the data.

```
protected void gvCurrCheckIns_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gvCurrCheckIns.Columns[8].HeaderText.Contains("(DESC)"))
            gvCurrCheckIns.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Checked IN (ASC)";
        else
            gvCurrCheckIns.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Checked IN (DESC)";
    }
```